# strange single quotes in shell script

Tags: shell

I wrote such scripts in test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
CPPCHECK_PATH=haha
SRC_TMP_PATH=asdf
xmlPath=test
cmd="$CPPCHECK_PATH/cppcheck $SRC_TMP_PATH --xml 2>$xmlPath"
`$cmd`
```

I run "sh -x test.sh" and the console output is:

```
sh -x test.sh 
+ CPPCHECK_PATH=haha
+ SRC_TMP_PATH=asdf
+ xmlPath=test
+ cmd='haha/cppcheck asdf --xml 2>test'
+ echo haha/cppcheck asdf --xml '2>test'
haha/cppcheck asdf --xml 2>test
++ haha/cppcheck asdf --xml '2>test'
```

why there is a pair of single quote around '2>test'？the script cannot run normally due to he single quotes. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes are there to tell you that it is being used as an argument rather than a redirect followed by a filename, since you can't include redirects in a variable this way. Remove the redirection from the variable and perform it separately.

Comment: I didn't quite catch you. do you mean that I should just write: $CPPCHECK_PATH/cppcheck $SRC_TMP_PATH --xml 2>$xmlPath, and don't set it to variable cmd?

Comment: Move the redirection out of the variable. And [read this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).